# Bootstrap Modal contain text box pop over is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have modal bootstrap inside that modal contain text box,i want popover the text box is not working

```
 $("#firstName").popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'left',
                content: 'sdsdfdsf'
            });


<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><input type="text" id="firstName"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This textbox inside the bootstrap modal

Comment: can you provide a bit more information about your problem and what is calling the modal like a jquerry function or event

Comment: modal means<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><input type="text" id="firstName"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

Comment: can you update the question to make it more readable

Comment: Take a look at the working version of it I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working version of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#firstName").popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'right',
                content: 'Your better description here.',
            });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLLe08bm/